# Create datatable in java

Tags: java, c#, lambda, datatable

In c#, I used datatable to read & compute values returning from SQL query like this

```
string connString = @"your connection string here";
string query = "select * from table";

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);        
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
conn.Open();

// create data adapter
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
// this will query your database and return the result to your datatable
da.Fill(dataTable);
```

In java, I don't find such feature. Evaluating & computing complex operations using join, filters is such a time & memory consuming with database.

So, I like to take the data in any object(like datatable in c#) then compute there only via lambda expressions which is much faster. I am thinking to use 2D arrays but they can store only particular type of values i.e. either Strings, int, etc. and also arrays doesn't provide such computing functions like Datatable does.

I there any other way to achieve the same functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest solution use javax.persistance.* JPA, define in persistance.xml your connection URL, persistance unit name. With native query you dont need to know ORM(object relation mapping) just standart SQL syntax. Then simple cast Object to corresponding primitive type.

```
factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
Query q = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT a.firstname, a.age FROM Author a");
List<Object[]> authors = q.getResultList();
for (Object[] a : authors) {
    String first = (String)a[0];
    int last = (int)a[1];
}
```

`List<Object[]>` is like 2D datatable.